# compare an array with two other arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

i have a set of 3 arrays which i would compare to eachother.
array a contain a set of values and the values of array b and c should be partly the same.

it is so that if let say `a[0] == b[0]` than is `c[0]` always a wrong value

for better explanation i try to show what i mean.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 3, 3, 4])
c = np.array([2, 2, 4, 3])

print(a == b)
# return: [False False True  True]
print(a == c)
# return: [True True False False]
```

as you can see the from both sets i have two True and two False. so if one of both is true the total should be true. when i do the following i get a single True/ False for an array. and the answers are what i want...

```
print((a == b).all())
# return: False
print((a == c).all())
# return: False

print(a.all() == (b.all() or c.all()))
# return: True
```

When i make the array b and c so that i have one vallue that in both cases is wrong i should end with a False

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 3, 3, 4])
c = np.array([5, 2, 4, 3])


print(a == b)
# return: [False False True  True]
print(a == c)
# return: [False True False False]

print((a == b).all())
# return: False
print((a == c).all())
# return: False
```

So far so Good

```
print(a.all() == (b.all() or c.all()))
# return: True
```

this part is not good this should be a False!!
How do i get an or function like this so that i end with an True when for each value in `a` an same value exist in `b` or `c`??

EDIT:
explanation about `a[0] == b[0]` than is `c[0]`:
i have an python function where phase information comes in and have to do some actions.
before that i want check if i have to do with an array of imaginary values or with an array with phase angles. I want to check this before i do something. The problem is the phase angle because the right side is the inverted phase +/- pi. so for every value i have two options. and yes most of the time it is an exclusive or but in the case +/- pi/2 it is not since both are true and that is also fine...

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "it is so that if let say `a[0] == b[0]` than is `c[0]` always a wrong value"? I see it as exclusive OR, but the rest of your question might imply you want normal OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example and explanation, I guess what you want is:

> For each position, **exactly** one of `b` or `c` has the same value as `a`

If that's the case, that can be done with the following code:

```
def is_exclusively_jointly_same(a, b, c):
    return np.logical_xor(a==b, a==c).all() # or use ^ below
    # return ((a==b)^(a==c)).all()
```

The `^` is exclusive or (XOR) operator, which returns `True` if and only if exactly one of its argument is `True`.

So the expression `(a==b)^(a==c)` means either `a==b` or `a==c`, but not both. Then the `.all()` checks whether this is true for all positions in the array.

Examples:

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([1,2,0,0,5])
>>> c=np.array([0,0,3,4,0])
>>> is_exclusively_jointly_same(a, b, c)
True

>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([0,2,0,0,5]) # First value both not 1
>>> c=np.array([0,0,3,4,0])
>>> is_exclusively_jointly_same(a, b, c)
False

>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([1,2,0,0,5]) # First value both 1
>>> c=np.array([1,0,3,4,0])
>>> is_exclusively_jointly_same(a, b, c)
False
```

If what you want is that:

> For each position, **at least** one of `b` and `c` should have the same value as `a`

, then you need to change to OR instead of XOR, as follows:

```
def is_jointly_same(a, b, c):
    return np.logical_or(a==b, a==c).all() # or use | below
    # return ((a==b) | (a==c)).all()
```

Examples:

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([1,2,0,0,5])
>>> c=np.array([0,0,3,4,0])
>>> is_jointly_same(a, b, c)
True

>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([0,2,0,0,5]) # First value both not 1
>>> c=np.array([0,0,3,4,0])
>>> is_jointly_same(a, b, c)
False

>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=np.array([1,2,0,0,5]) # First value both 1
>>> c=np.array([1,0,3,4,0])
>>> is_jointly_same(a, b, c)
True
```

The key here is that `.all()` should be applied *once* as final aggregator, when each individual values has already been calculated. So when you see that you are applying `.all()` multiple times, you should be concerned.

Comment: I get an error in python3 when i use you're apraoch...  
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Did you pass in numpy array? I think that error happens if you compare lists, not numpy array. Also, can you clarify which one, XOR or OR,  is your intention?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, for the OR case it is incorrect. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You want a logical `OR`:

```
np.logical_or(a==b, a==c).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way instead:

```
(a==b).all() or (a==c).all()
```

Comment: `(a==b).all()` is False when not al values are true so you get two times a False and `(a==b).all() or (a==c).all()` don understand that...

Answer (score -1):

> Actually all() function Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).
>   And in programming language 0 is considered as false and any other integer is considered as true.
>   So here in your array a,b,c every element is non zero and a.all(), b.all() and c.all() they all are seperately returning true so finally you are getting true.